# Microwave Oven: Switching Magnetron (Transformer) with SSR

Tags: transformer, solid-state-relay

I've got a used microwave oven and want to improve it with a digital user interface.

Is it ok to switch the magnetron (more precisely: the transformer from 230V 50Hz to some kV followed by a diode and a capacitor) using an SSR (solid state relais), or should I use a mechanical relais?

One more burning question: Is it ok to use phase cutting to regulate the microwave power or will this lead to problems with the transformer, the rectifier or the magnetron?

Thanks
  Hansi

Comment: How could anyone know without a circuit diagram and a skill set that covers microwave oven design?

Comment: I asked here in the hope to find somebody in this field or somebody who investigated the inrush current of a microwave oven or any similar transformer --> rectifier setup.

Comment: You don't mention inrush current investigation in your question

Answer (score 4):

Normally the transformer feeding the magnetron is just switched on/off by a relay or triac. A relay or SSR capable of handling a somewhat inductive load would be easiest.

Here's a schematic of a very simple old-school microwave oven. Yours may have such a schematic stuck internally. Possibly if you added the schematic and some photos someone might be able to give you a more precise answer.

[image]

If you only interrupt the circuit going through the timer switch and **don't muck** with the **interlocks and fuses** it **might** be relatively safe to do this (from the pov of safety from leaking microwaves), but keep in mind the lethal voltages internally (both the magnetron high voltage and the mains), and the potential for fires.

There are many opportunities for serious injury or death in this endeavor, so I have to suggest that buying a new $50-$150 microwave would be a better course of action. I have modified a consumer microwave oven to create gaseous plasma inside a vessel but it takes quite a bit of knowledge and care to do this relatively safely.

Comment: "I have modified a consumer microwave oven to create gaseous plasma inside a vessel" - Spehro, you continue to surprise me every day.

Comment: Thanks for posting this schematic. My oven unfortunately doesn't have one inside, but I've drawn one by hand (following the wires) and its quite similar (but a messy drawing). And as you said, I will definitely not play with the locks, the other security features, and the high voltage part.

From the schematic I see that the heater of the magnetron is also supplied from the transformer, which means that phase cutting would impact that too, therefore no (primary side) phase cutting possible.

And, not least, I'm curious what you've changed to create a plasma. :-)